# How to check if a node in xpath has a certain child x but also doesn't have a child y

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I'm trying to get the non-forked repositories of a given github users. Currently I managed to get all the repositories with this xpath query:

```
parser.xpath("//ul[@data-filterable-for='your-repos-filter']/li/div/div/h3/a/@href").map{|repository| ...}
```

The point is I need to filter out the ones that the next 'sibling' of the last div is **not** a `span`, something like:

```
parser.xpath("//ul[@data-filterable-for='your-repos-filter']/li/div/div/h3 and not span/a/@href").map{|repository| ...}
```

The HTML I'm looking for is the [following](https://github.com/DominikAngerer?tab=repositories) (inspecting one of the forked repositories):

```
<li class="col-12 d-flex width-full py-4 border-bottom public fork" itemprop="owns" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Code">
  <div class="col-10 col-lg-9 d-inline-block">
    <div class="d-inline-block mb-1">
      <h3 class="wb-break-all">
        <a href="/DominikAngerer/rails-boilerplate" itemprop="name codeRepository" >
        rails-boilerplate</a>

      </h3>

        <span class="f6 text-gray mb-1">
          Forked from <a class="muted-link" href="/polomasta/rails-boilerplate">polomasta/rails-boilerplate</a>
        </span>

    </div>

    <div>
        <p class="col-9 d-inline-block text-gray mb-2 pr-4" itemprop="description">
          Ruby on Rails Storyblok Starter Boilerplate
        </p>
    </div>
```

When is not a forked repository, those that I'm looking for, there is no such `<span class="f6 text-gray mb-1">`

Is it possible such query, if so how?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". We need the smallest runnable code, the smallest input HTML that demonstrates the problem, and your required output _in the question itself_. Currently we don't know what page you're looking at, and if we did, asking us to retrieve it and dig through it to find the matching node is off-topic. Those are things you do to help us help you. But, as a hint, rarely should you use an explicit path to your desired note. Find significant way-points instead.

Comment: @theTinMan sorry hope it's more clarifying right now

Comment: Now write a bit of code that loads that HTML, parses it, and demonstrates the problem you're having. That's all in "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)"

Comment: Also, GitHub has an [API](https://developer.github.com/v3/). Why aren't you using it? Scraping was useful years ago, but with REST and APIs available scraping is much less desirable; It results in fragile code, it's generally slower, and, the sites you're scraping are able to provide more reliable service because they can allocate for it. They're also a lot happier when you use their API because it doesn't beat up their server and network just so you can throw away the majority of the content they passed to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following XPath to select the links of non-forked repositories :

```
//div[@class="d-inline-block mb-1"][not(./span[contains(.,"Forked from")])]//@href
```

Output : 17 nodes for https://github.com/DominikAngerer?tab=repositories